# Autoplay not working on my Javascript Slider

Tags: javascript

My goal is to coding a slider in Javascript, with a Class inside. But I meet 2 issues :

- the Autoplay does not work
- if I click on the Pause Button, and then click again on the play button, the autoplay does not work either

The HTML page is located there :
http://p4547.phpnet.org/bikes/slider.html

Here is my Javascript code :

```
class Diaporama {
  constructor() {
    this.controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
    this.slides = document.querySelectorAll('#diaporama .slide');
    this.currentSlide = 0;
    this.n = null;
    this.playing = true;
    this.pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
    this.next = document.getElementById('next');
    this.previous = document.getElementById('previous');
  }

// Afficher les boutons previous, play, pause, next :
  controlling() {
    for(let i=0; i < this.controls.length; i++){
        this.controls[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
  }

// Slider Automatique :
  goToSlide(n) {
    this.slides[this.currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    this.currentSlide = (n + this.slides.length)%this.slides.length;
    this.slides[this.currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
    console.log(this.currentSlide);
  }

  nextSlide() {
    this.goToSlide(this.currentSlide + 1);
  }

  previousSlide() {
    this.goToSlide(this.currentSlide - 1);
  }

  slideInterval() {
    setInterval(this.nextSlide,5000);
  }

  pauseSlideshow() {
    this.pauseButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-play"></i>';
    this.playing = false;
    clearInterval(this.slideInterval);
  }

  playSlideshow() {
    this.pauseButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pause"></i>';
    this.playing = true;
    this.slideInterval = setInterval(this.nextSlide,5000);
  }

  nextItem() {
  next.onclick = () => {
    this.pauseSlideshow();
    this.nextSlide();
  }
  }

  previousItem() {
    previous.onclick = () => {
      this.pauseSlideshow();
      this.previousSlide();
    }
  }

// Changement de slide par les touches du clavier :
  clickKeyboard() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", ({keyCode}) => {
      if(keyCode === 37){
          this.nextSlide();
      }
      else if(keyCode === 39){
          this.previousSlide();
      }
  })
}

};

let slider = new Diaporama();
slider.controlling();
slider.goToSlide(0);
slider.nextSlide();
slider.previousSlide();
slider.pauseSlideshow();
slider.playSlideshow();
slider.nextItem();
slider.previousItem();
slider.clickKeyboard();
```

Comment: check your dev-tools console for errors -- ('Uncaught TypeError: this.goToSlide is not a function')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is inside `playslideShow`. When it calls this.nextSlide inside `setInterval`, the scope of `this` has changed. `this` refers to the window.

You can use `bind()` in this case, to make sure it refers to the slider object:

```
playSlideshow() {
    this.pauseButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pause"></i>';
    this.playing = true;
    this.slideInterval = setInterval(this.nextSlide.bind(this),5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh no, sorry, I found out why my Pause button was bugging.
I just added a new function :

```
  restart() {
      this.pauseButton.onclick = () => {
      if(this.playing){ this.pauseSlideshow(); }
      else{ this.playSlideshow(); }
    }
  }
```

It works fine now !